# I used NAV tags in HTML and it doesn't work as I wanted

Tags: css, html

This is my css and my html5 to make a website but the navigation bar doesn't lying in the row.

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <div>
      <center>
        <ul class="menu">
          <li>
            <a href="Home.html"> <button>HOME</button> </a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Gymset.html"><button>GYM SETS</button></a>
            <ul class="menu-con">
              <li><a href="#"><button>SET TẬP GYM TRONG NHÀ</a>
                <ul class="menu-con2">
                  <li><a href="#"><button>TẠ TẬP TAY</button></a></li>
                  <li><a href="#"><button>TẠ TẬP CHÂN</button></a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
              <li><a href="#"><button>SET TẬP GYM NGOÀI TRỜI</button></a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><button>SET TẬP AN TOÀN</button></a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="Dotap.html"><button>Đồ tập</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Gio hang.html"><button>Giỏ hàng</button></a></li>
          <li><a href="Lienhe.html"><button>Liên hệ</button></a></li>
      </center>
    </div>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Can you guys help me to fix that errors?

Comment: `<ul>`s should not have `<div>` children (and what's your CSS?)

Comment: `<center>` doesn't exist anymore

Comment: `ul#menu` has no closing tag

Comment: `button` is not a valid child of `a`, see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a particularly **Permitted Content**

Answer (score 2):

`<nav>` is a simple element just like a `<div>`. It's considered best practice to use a nav tag when the content of your element is a navigation component. It's only semantic, and doesn't  have different styling.

If you want to create an horizontal navigation you can use a list and style it so each li will float left and you'll probably want to remove the list-style.

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

It's also recommended not to use button inside a `<a>`, you can style your `<a>` tag to look like a button. Here's an example:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #bada55;
}

li {
  float: left;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 8px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #585858;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>
      <a href="Home.html"> HOME </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Gymset.html">GYM SETS</a>
      <ul class="menu-con">
        <li><a href="#">TRONG NHÀ</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">NGOÀI TRỜI</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TOÀN</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="Dotap.html">Đồ tập</a></li>
    <li><a href="Gio hang.html">Giỏ hàng</a></li>
    <li><a href="Lienhe.html">Liên hệ</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this code

```
<html>
<style>
    body{
        color: white;
    }

    ul{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    ul li{
        float: left;
        width: 200px;
        height: fit-content;
        background: black;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 20px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }

    ul li a{
        color: white;
        display: block;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    ul li a:hover{
        background-color: green;
    }

    ul li ul li{
        display: none;
    }

    ul li:hover ul li{
        display: block;
    }

</style>
<body>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="...">HOME</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a>GYM SETS</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a>SET TẬP GYM TRONG NHÀ</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a>SET TẬP GYM NGOÀI TRỜI</a></li>
                            <li><a>SET TẬP AN TOÀN</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="...">Đồ tập</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="...">Giỏ hàng</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="...">Liên hệ</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: A good answer should briefly explain how it works instead of relying solely on code.

Answer (score 0):

May be this can works for you, also if you're building a responsive site, you need to learn more about mobile first and change some of css rules, adding media querys...

list-style: none, remove the default style for lists.

tag is deprecated but you can still use it, but for better practice you can use display: flex; and justify-content-center;

[A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

You can add several submenus like this way...

```css
* {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        nav {
            background: #111;
        }

        ol,
        ul {
            list-style: none;
        }
        .menu {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
        }
        .menu li a {
            background: #111;
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: 20px;
            display: block;
        }

        .menu li a:hover {
            background: green;
        }

        .menu li ul {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 140px;
        }

        .menu li:hover>ul {
            display: block;
        }

        .menu li ul li {
            position: relative;
        }

        .menu li ul li ul {
            right: -140px;
            top: 0;
        }
```

```html
    <nav>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>
                <a href="Home.html"> HOME </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="Gymset.html">GYM SETS</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">TRONG NHÀ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NGOÀI TRỜI</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TOÀN</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Dotap.html">Đồ tập</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">TRONG NHÀ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">NGOÀI TRỜI</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">TOÀN</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">TRONG NHÀ</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">NGOÀI TRỜI</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">TOÀN</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">TRONG NHÀ</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">NGOÀI TRỜI</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">TOÀN</a>
                                        <ul>
                                            <li><a href="#">TRONG NHÀ</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">NGOÀI TRỜI</a></li>
                                            <li><a href="#">TOÀN</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>
                                </ul>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Gio hang.html">Giỏ hàng</a></li>
            <li><a href="Lienhe.html">Liên hệ</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```